# Simple AngularJS Tab Widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

Is there a more concise/pragmatic way to create tabbed widgets with angular that doesn't include ui.bootstrap?  The tab module is fantastic but i'm trying to create a lean site built with stylus and I find that ui.bootstrap is rather complex and very intertwined with the Twitter bootstrap css.  I dont have much experience with building directives, but would that be the best approach?  After mixing a few examples that I found, this is what I came up with...

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-init="selectTab='tab1'" ng-switch>
    <ul class="tab-header">
      <li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='tab1'}" ng-click="selectTab='tab1'">tab1</li>
      <li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='tab2'}" ng-click="selectTab='tab2'">tab2</li>
      <li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='tab3'}" ng-click="selectTab='tab3'">tab3</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-switch on="selectTab">
      <div class="tab-content" ng-switch-when="tab1">tab1 contents</div>
      <div class="tab-content" ng-switch-when="tab2">tab2 contents</div>  
      <div class="tab-content" ng-switch-when="tab3">tab3 contents</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/js02sixty/pen/HELKA)

Comment: Perhaps generate tab-header dynamically was a good idea.